# flot opacity of pie not supported?

Tags: flot

I do not see any examples of a pie chart with opacity and the fill property is not supported in pie charts as it is for bar charts. Can someone please provide an example of a pie chart with opacity or transparency setting (for the pie chart itself, not the labels)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an RGBA value when specifying the color for your data series to set transparency:

```
var data = [{
    label: "Yes",
    data: 50,
    color: 'rgba(89, 120, 182, 1)'
}, {
    label: "No",
    data: 150,
    color: 'rgba(89, 120, 182, .5)'
}];
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5JyT8/1/)